# Laravel PDF::loadHtml Utf8 issue

Tags: laravel, utf-8, pdf-generation

I use PDF::loadHtml for creating pdf in Laravel 5.3

everything works good but i have utf8 problem i cant solv it

My codes :

```
 $text="<html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Birinci gün</h2>
    <table style="width:100%;" border="1">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>Həftə</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">Dərs</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">Vaxt</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">Müəllim</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">Korpus</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">Otaq</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th rowspan="2">1</th>
                                       <td style="padding-left:5px">Üst</td>
                                        <td><input name="ders[]" value=""></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center"><input name="vaxt[]" value=""></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center"><input name="teacher[]" value=""></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center"><input name="korpus[]" value=""></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center"><input name="otaq[]" value=""></td>
                                    </tr>      </tbody></table>

    </body>
    </html>";
    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' .$text, 'UTF-8');
            return $pdf->stream();
```

Comment: Are you using this package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ??

Comment: @nikhil_gandhi Yes the package is Dompdf

Comment: You are stacking double quotes, move the view code to a blade file

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is what you need to do.

1. Move your code to blade file. Never write HTML code in your controller.
2. In your blade file, set the UTF-8 Metatag:
3. In your controller's method

   $pdf = PDF::loadView('PDF_NAME.pdf', $data);

   return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

Comment: This Issue has been solved , The way to solv the matter you need to change the font family with css adding those following lines :                       
  *{
            font-family:"DeJaVu Sans Mono",monospace;
        }

Answer (score 1):

`PDF::loadHtml` not support utf-8 characters very well and pure php libraries is too hard for using specially in laravel and many of them has this problem too.
I make laravel composer package for do it very very simple by develop and simplify tcpdf.

Just Install it by this command:

> composer require vatttan/apdf

Now its available in where ever you like. For example in your view you can use:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Vatttan\Apdf\Apdf;
Route::get('/', function () {
    $apdf = new Apdf();
    $apdf->print('<p style="text-align: right">Birinci gün</p>');
});
```

Finished!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience , This question already archived and solved from several years. The problem solved by changing fonts.

Comment: Yes. But in some languages like Persian show characters vise versa and i post answer for other developers that encounter that.

Comment: I got it, Thank you very much again, It is nice to me discovering your solution also.